# Creating cascading lookup columns in sharepoint 2013 foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, cascading

I am trying to create cascading lookup columns in my library.

I have already tried to use a jquery solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using, but didn't find a working answer for the foundation version. I know a good solution would be to choose a paying version, unfortunatelly that is out of the question.

The goal is to be able to choose one or more of those people whom are linked to the former chosen platform, this to evite people from having lists with too many items.

In some other cases I will also need to use cascading lookup columns (only one choice)

Unfortunatelly I am not a programmer, so please be rather complete with the provided code.

[image: Tables for cascading lookup]

The goal is to use this stuff as metadata for documents.

Concretely seen I would like to have an invitation and presency list as metadata to meeting reports. However my goal is also to use simmilar techniques on other metadata.

In addition, the goal of the groups I want to use is to manage accesses, for now it is not a goal to add all kinds of groups, if unnescesary (some staff members are quite alergic to too many groups )

On top of that I am totally unfamiliar with the possibility to use groups and their members als metadata. Unfortunately I have had none possibility to follow any course whatshowever about sharepoint.

However, if you can give me a solution to make this work using groups, I am pretty pleased too, that would give me extra strenght to defend using groups :)

Comment: Why are you doing this using cascading lookup columns? You can just add multiple users against each platform by creating a Users and Groups column thereby getting the users against each platform. Just curious.